# laravel 5.2 Authentication Failure

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hello Guys i am new to laravel. When the new user register with authentication i am this error message. How to resolve my problem
The Authentication Failure with this error message.

```
Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\customer given.
```

My controller is

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new customer;
        $user->name=Input::get('name');
        $user->email=Input::get('email');
        $user->password=Input::get('password');
        $user->save();

        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect::home();
    }
```

and my routes

```
        Route::get('register', 'testing@index');
        Route::post('store', 'testing@store');
        Route::get('login', 'testing@create');
        Route::post('logout', 'testing@destroy');
```

and my register page is

```
<form action="store" method="post">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off">
        <br>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off">
        <br>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="password" autocomplete="off">
        <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Please help me guys how to register,login and logout with complete authentation.

Thanks you and welcome your suggestions.

Comment: Do you have a specfifc reason for not using the default registration and login process that laravel provides to you? Your problem is ofcrouse that you use customer instead of App\User - if you want to use your own model ensure it's an Instance of Authenticable

Comment: @FrankProvost. First i Came from php. I want to know to how authentication works. I am following laracasts from jeffrey way tutorials.

Comment: @FrankProvost. I already used App\customer. when i use Auth::login($user);
        return redirect::home(); I am getting error. But i removed it auth code above the user is saved in database table. what is wrong in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your actual model of customer I try to give you the best matching answer.

If you are very new to laravel the best appraoch ist to use

```
php artisan make:auth
```

To create:

- Home View
- App Layout
- Auth Routes
- Auth Controller
- Password Reset

This will be done for you, using the default, already existing, App\User model. If you DO NOT want to user the default App\User and you want to use your App\Customer for authentication, then you will need to at least make your model extend Authenticable

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Customer extends Authenticatable
{
...
}
```

Without this you will surely receive the given error. However, you will still need to ensure that there are the required fields on your Customer model - like email, password, remember token etc. If you do not want to use these you will need to make further adaptions within your authentication controller.

As mentioned the best approach for beginners is using the generated auth. You can find more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication

**Be careful** - php artisan make:auth will create a few views and it will overwrite existing ones with the same name.

e.g.

- /resources/views/home.blade.php
- /resources/views/layout/app.blade.php
- /resources/views/auth/login.blade.php
- /resources/views/auth/register.blade.php

and a few more within auth

Looking at your code you could simply try replacing

```
$user = new customer;
```

with

```
$user = new User
```

and ofcourse pull in the user model

```
use App\User;
```

Comment: I agree with Frank provost.